# Java - Zero out the rows/columns of 2d array if it contains a target number

Tags: java, arrays, performance, matrix

Given a mxn matrix that looks like this:
1034
1234
3560

Need to output something like this:
0000
1030
0000

*Target number is 0.

Here's my solution, but I think it's not very efficient (both space and running time which I believe is O(m^2 * n)) and was wondering if there are simpler and more efficient ways to do this. If yes, what is it?

```
int[][] m = { { 1, 0, 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 3, 5, 6, 0 } };  
m = zero(m, 0);

public static int[][] zero(int[][] m, int num) {

    int rows = m.length;
    int columns = m[0].length;
    int [][] myInt = new int[rows][];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        myInt[i] = m[i].clone();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (myInt[i][j] == num) {
                m[i] = new int[columns];
                for(int k = 0; k < rows; k++){
                    m[k][j] = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
    return m;
}
```

Basically I clone the input matrix first, then iterate through each row and check if the row contains my target number. If yes, then I set the entire row in the original matrix to zero. Then I do another loop to set the column which contains the target number to zero. I cloned the matrix in the beginning so the checking is always against the cloned reference matrix instead of the modified one at each iteration.

Comment: It is not clear from the example (without code) what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the target number in my example is 0. So need to zero out the rows and columns of the matrix which contain 0.

Comment: There is no question, there will be no answer.

Comment: The question is are there more efficient ways to solve this problem than the one I posted. If yes, then what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose using BitSet for row/column indices.

```
public static void zero(int[][] m, int num) {

    int rows = m.length;
    int columns = m[0].length;
    BitSet rowsToClear = new BitSet(rows);
    BitSet columnsToClear = new BitSet(columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] == num) {
                rowsToClear.set(i);
                columnsToClear.set(j);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = rowsToClear.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0;
             i = rowsToClear.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
        Arrays.fill(m[i], 0);
    }
    for (int j = columnsToClear.nextSetBit(0); j >= 0;
            j = columnsToClear.nextSetBit(j + 1)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //return m;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the running time of this algorithm?

Comment: The for-for takes NxM and is the decisive factor. `BitSet` in this case is an indirect long, and `nextSetBit` is then `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros` - quite optimal. An `int` i.o. a `BitSet` might be more optimal, but hey, a two-dimensional array is not optimal too in Java. `Arrays.fill` though is nice.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question and have developed a solution for it.

I am hoping for some feedback regarding the code about how it's better/worse and it's runtime and space complexity. Pretty new to all this :)

```
public static void zeroMatrix(int[][] arr1)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> coord = new ArrayList<>();

    int row = arr1.length; 
    int column = arr1[0].length;
    for(int i=0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i][j]==0)
            { 
                coord.add((10*i) + j);
            }       
        }
    }

    for(int n : coord)
    {
         int j=n%10;
         int i=n/10; int k=0;
        int l=0;
        while(k<row)
        {
            arr1[k][j]=0;
            k++;
        }
        while(l<column)
        {
            arr1[i][l]=0;
            l++;
        }
    }
}
```